# How to change color of hyperlink after click on it and stayed colored after reloading page?

Tags: jquery

I have hyperlinks in my drop-down-menu and I want to change color of certain hyperlink when I click on that. My code works, but when this link point to another page (= reloading page), this color-changes disappear, it doesn't work.

Example:

```
1. <a href="#">this works</a>
2. <a href="/contact">doesn't work</a>
```

My code [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtvbs4mn/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">SubItem1</a>  
            <a href="#">SubItem2</a>          
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu a").bind("click", function(){
        $("#menu a").removeClass("menuCSSlbl");
        $(this).addClass("menuCSSlbl");
    });
});
```

Comment: you will have to maintain the state somewhere. like local storage.

Comment: `Cookies` can be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about to use a localStorage, but I was not sure. I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround (I think you can use it) is to use css `:active`. Comment your js code and try with this:

```
#menu a:link { color: blue; } /** link */
#menu a:visited { color: purple; } /** visited, this is what you are looking for */
#menu a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } /** onhover */
#menu a:active { color: #666; } /** onmousedown */
```

You can set the pseudo selectors to each anchor separately, so it can be useful in this case.

Remember that if the user deletes his navigate history, `:visited` elements will be cleaned.

And yes, the other workaround is to use cookies or localStorage, depending your needs.